# Regex Expression should not be Compulsory

Tags: regex

i have a regex expression for a textbox which is accepting only 1 place after decimal and value not greater than 6. 
but currently it's compulsory/mandatory textbox which i don't want.

```
^([0-5](?:\.\d)?|6(?:\.0)?)$
```

**Accepted value:** 
6.0 
5.9 
0.0 
1.1 
5   
6   
blank 
**not accepted:** 
6.01 
6.1 
5.99 
0.00 
null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: `^((?:[0-5](?:\.\d)?|6(?:\.0)?)?)$`

I changed your outer group to non-capturing and optional and added new capturing group to capture everything but start and end of line.